# Jenkins takes ages to complete some builds?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, webdriver-io

Jenkins takes ages to complete some builds?

- Plugins installed: NodeJS | HTML Report Plugin | Post Build Task
- Jenkins is correctly aligned to my nodeJS folder housed on my local
  machine.
- Im also running Jenkins via a .war file.

For example build 1 will execute a simple automation test script and complete however other builds seem to take ages to complete?

[image]

Comment: @Fang how about now?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading jenkins.war to an older version resolved the issue.